# Psuedo-element ::before is not displaying

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

The pseudo-element exists in the DOM, but it is not visible.

I've tried fiddling with many different options but I don't see what is wrong with it. The div element is wrapped in an empty span where it is called.

style.scss

```
.tickBox {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  background-color: $grey6;
  overflow: visible;

  &::before{ 
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: .9em;
    left: -4em;
    width: 4em;
    height: .3em;
    background: $grey6;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

tickbox.js

```
const TickBox = () => (
  <div styleName={'tickBox'} />
);
```

The tickbox circle is displayed correctly and when I hover over it in the DOM element viewer I can see that the ::before pseudo element is there and in the correct shape, but it is not displaying.

Comment: add `z-index:0` to parent element

Comment: `z-index: -1` will position the pseudo element _behind_ the `tickBox` background. Is this what you want to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with `z-index` make it like `999`.

Comment: This works thank you! Will accept answer when the timer allows

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Answer (score -2):

You don't seem to be using a pseudo-element at the moment. Try this setting `.help-tip` to `.help-tip::after` and giving `content: ""` and

```
display: inline-block:
    .help-tip::after {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url("/assets/small-help-icon.gif");
    }
```

Comment: Are you answering a different question?